# Does $\pi_1$ have a right adjoint?

Tags: ct.category-theory, at.algebraic-topology

Eilenberg and Mac Lane showed that given a group $G$ there exists a pointed topological space $X_G$ such that $\pi(X_G,\bullet)\cong G$. It is obviously a way to "invert direction" to the functor $\pi_1\colon \mathbf{Top}^\bullet\to \mathbf{Grp}$ to a functor $\mathcal K\colon \mathbf{Grp}\to \mathbf{Top}^\bullet$ such that $\pi_1(\mathcal K(G),\bullet)\cong G$ (almost by definition). This is equivalent to say that there exists a natural transformation (equivalence, in this case) between $\pi_1\circ\mathcal K$ and $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{Grp}}$, which turns out to resemble some sort of *counity*.

It would be wonderful if I could define an adjunction between the two categories in exam, given by the two functors. Everytime I try to think about some sort of *unity* to this hypotetical adjunction I poorly fail: considering the vast literature in the field of algebraic topology, I believe in only two possible cases. The first, nothing interesting arises from this adjunction. The second, there is no sort of adjunction.

The key point, quite trivial, to answer is: it is well known that an adjunction is uniquely determined by one among *unity* and *counity*, provided the one is universal. But $\boldsymbol\varepsilon\colon \pi_1\circ\mathcal K\to \mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{Grp}}$ is an *equivalence*: can I conclude that it is universal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the more general setting the answer is no. Left adjoints preserve colimits and it is not true that $\pi_{1}(X\vee Y)\cong \pi_{1}(X)\ast\pi_{1}(Y)$ for all spaces $X,Y$ (even compact metric spaces). For instance, if $(\mathbb{HE},x)$ is the usual Hawaiian earring, let $X=Y=C\mathbb{HE}=\mathbb{HE}\times I/\mathbb{HE}\times\{1\}$ be the cone on the Hawaiian earring with basepoint the image of $(x,0)$ in the quotient. It is a theorem of Griffiths that $\pi_{1}(C\mathbb{HE}\vee C\mathbb{HE})$ is uncountable and not the free product of trivial groups.

Answer (score 34):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the homotopy category of connected pointed CW complexes.  Then the functor $\pi_1:\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Grp}$ does indeed have a right adjoint.  The cleanest way to define it is to use the simplicial classifying space functor $B:\mathbf{Grp}\to\mathcal{C}$.  For the unit of the adjunction you need a natural homotopy class of maps $X\to B(\pi_1(X))$.  This can be done by obstruction theory, by induction up the skeleta of $X$.  Alternatively, one can define a more canonical map from $|SX|$ (the geometric realisation of the singular complex) to $B(\pi_1(X))$ by simplicial methods, and then use the fact that there is a natural map $|SX|\to X$ which is a homotopy equivalence when $X\in\mathcal{C}$. The first place I would look for more details would be Peter May's old book on simplicial objects in algebraic topology.

Comment: Goerss-Jardine is probably going to be more useful than Peter May's book, which is really outdated.

Comment: That copy of the book is copyright-infringing (not that I care), and it's probably better if you can avoid posting it on MO.

Comment: Sanity check: The unit of adjunction corresponds to taking the universal covering space with its monodromy action, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

This question was answered a long time ago, but let me mention a couple of relevant papers which invest on Fosco's intuition and partially confirms it.

> *Paul C. Kainen*, **Weak adjoint functors**.  P.C. Math Z (1971) 122: 1.

The main point of the paper is the observation that $\mathsf{K}( -, n)$ is a weak  adjoint for $\pi_n$. The paper insists many subtleties, like (non-)preservation of limits and (non-)functoriality of the weak adjoints.  Very soon Kainen changed research topic, but it is worthy to mention also the paper below.

> *Paul C. Kainen*, **Universal coefficient theorems for generalized homology and stable cohomotopy**, Pacific J. Math. 37 (1971) 397– 407.